# Reading file from Dropbox to Android

Tags: android, dropbox

I am using Android Studio and Dropbox Sync API to read files from Dropbox. I am struggling to implement the instructions at the official Dropbox site for SYNC API.

Can someone show me the steps and the java code which reads a simple .txt file from Dropbox which has the text Hello World!.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: I have but i am stuck at linking account and creating the dbxfile system. That's why i want help from someone to show me a simple read .txt file(Hello World!) from Dropbox.

Comment: This is complete tutorial here you posted. Have you imported libraries and installed SDK properly?

Comment: Yes i did. I am sure about it. But i still have error when i put         DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount()); it says unhandled exception. Unauthorized.

Comment: What error? Please post it here.

Comment: OK, i thinks an image is better than words   http://i61.tinypic.com/11kjq4x.jpg

Comment: add try catch block. It should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, they are alright.

Comment: It doesnt work. The bad thing is the dropbox tutorial is bad and other codes from other websites don't work.

Comment: Whats the problem now?

Comment: Ok i put the DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount()); inside the try and catch. It shows no error but when i run the app after a while the app is closed automatically. I don't know what the heck is wrong with the Dropbox SYNC. I have followed all the instructions and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? There are also working samples apps included with the SDK. I recommend running those to get acquainted with the SDK.

Answer (score -1):

You must catch all the missing catches, eg

```
catch(DbxException.Unauthorized unauthorized) { }
catch (DbxPath.InvalidPathException e) { }
catch (DbxException e) {     }
catch (IOException e) {     }
```

Then you can compile this section :-)